# Problem of $\pi$- and $\lambda$-systems

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, problem-solving

I have some trouble with a theoretic-like exercise about measure theory, and $\pi$- and $\lambda$-systems, and I would like to have some help. The problem is stated in the book *Mathematical Statistics, Jun Shao*, exercise 5 of section 1.6, page 74:

[image: problem]

I am somewhat puzzled because I expected $\mathcal{D}$ to be a $\sigma$-algebra (the exercise would be vacuosly easy then), but to be a $\lambda$-system is strictly weaker. I suppose one has to use some trick about $\pi$-systems, but I cannot guess what to use because of the non-constructive definition of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by some subset.

Any suggestion is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is lacking in $\mathcal D$ that makes it not be a $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Can you please retype the problem here? It's awkward when the question is not self contained.

Comment: @DilipSarwate $\mathcal{D}$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra because the $A_i$ need to be disjoint.

Comment: @NateEldredge I have included the picture :-)